# Different instances of same infrastructure in terraform azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cloud-services, infrastructure

I have written part of an infrastructure in terraform connected to azure with a resourcegroup which has a virtual network and consists of two different SQL databases. The idea is to use this for different customers, which means I want to build up this infrastructure several times to create one resourcegroup with all the mentioned stuff for each customer. However I can't seem to understand how to get different instances of it? Right now the resourcegroup in azure gets overwritten whenever I try to create another one with a different name.

I would also like to ask about virtual networks. In the structure described above, will all customers be isolated from eachother with own resourcegroup containing a virtual network?
I read somewhere that virtual networks are good because they isolate so I am just wondering if that is true.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to deploy terraform template to different resource group. And for the vnets - yes. unless you peer\connect vnets with vpn they are isolated from each other.